# confirm exiting dialog exits without confirmation

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i am trying to save data upon exiting an activity of my app.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

super.onBackPressed();
if(loadInboxPreferencesCurrent()==false){
    showAlertUserDialogInbox();
}

}

public void showAlertUserDialogInbox() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builderMiniAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builderMiniAlert.setMessage("Do you want to exit without saving your App. Inbox Settings..\n\nDo you want to Save now. ?")
               .setCancelable(false); // disallow user to hit the 'back' button

    builderMiniAlert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            //Save settings here
            onBackPresedNSave();

        }
    });
    builderMiniAlert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "To set your App. Inbox Settings later, press menu key and select Save Inbox Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            arg0.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builderMiniAlert.setTitle("Ultimate Sms Inbox Alert...");

    builderMiniAlert.show();

}
```

> Now the real problem is after pressing back button, the dialog shows for a second and disappears without user clicking yes / no buttons.

Comment: save your data in `onPause()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **super.onBackPressed** in

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed(); //remove this because this will close the activity
    if(loadInboxPreferencesCurrent()==false){
         showAlertUserDialogInbox();
    }

}
```

and make sure you handle finishing the activity somewhere else like after clicking positive/negative button in dialog.

I am not sure though if what you are trying to do is the best approach on saving data.

You should probably look at the activity's onSaveInstanceState() but if your aim is to only save after the user's confirmation then your first approach will do.